# Two gems with the same namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an existing gem called `company_name`.  It has the usual module with several helper classes under it, like so:

*`company_name` gem*

```
module CompanyName
  class Log
    # ...
  end
end
```

I want to create another gem that shares the namespace with the first gem.

*`another_company_name` gem*

```
module CompanyName
  class Calc

  end
end
```

Will this approach play well with Rails autoloading?  Are there any hidden gotchas to this method?

Comment: have you read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112045/load-two-ruby-modules-gems-with-the-same-name ?

Comment: @adantj that pretty much covers it, thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 0):

It wont work, the latest gem that gets loaded will override the first one. You need to change one or the other, or wrap one into a higher level of abstraction but im not sure why you wanna do that.